Nestjs websocket gateway params
How is it possible to pass params within websocket url?
I'm using path to run websocket on a specific url:
@WebSocketGateway(8080, { path: 'my/custom/url' })

Here it is needed to pass a param in url and get it in handleConnection function. I tried:
@WebSocketGateway(8080, { path: 'my/custom/url/:id' })

But it fails to build. So, what is the right way?
